# False Flag Highlights

Tags: bug

The introduction of the new, spiffy top bar has bought with it a recent bug.

The highlight for flags now sits there, glowing bright yellow, urging me to atend to the task of weeding through the flags and to submit my considered judgement to the wisdom of the crowd.

Sadly, over the last couple of weeks, the number of flags has been invariably overstated. I log in, experience the Pavlovian rush of adrenalin and guilt and immediately click through only to find... *nothing*.

[image: The top bar LIES!!]

Like the good Russian doctor's hounds, I am unable to resist the siren call of the flag highlight; please help me, fix this bug so that I don't have to live with the weight of defeated expectations and the wretched frustration of stymied voting when I visit the site.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is fixed now, kind of. The top bar shows the number of flags in the queue, but the actual flag list used to filter out flags you've already seen, and you had already reviewed those 6. It now shows all 10k flags, but dims the ones you've seen

Comment: Thanks Michael: that is much better.